# Can't get size of elements and the classes in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I an trying to read all elements with name class shadow-non mb-3 and iterate that many times to extract readHeading and readCollapse. But the code returns zero for the first one and thus the loop doesn't run. It also doens't find readHeading and readCollapse. I have tried xpath and searching by name.

MyCode

```
values="/0"
ga=pandas.read_csv("contracts/adresses.csv")
for i in range (ga.size-1):
        fj=ga.iloc[i][0]
        # driver.get("https://etherscan.io/address/"+str(fj))
        break
        

time.sleep(5)
      
driver.get("https://etherscan.io/address/"+str(fj)+"#readContract")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

frame = wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"readcontractiframe")))

expandall = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[@onclick='expandCollapseAll()']")))
expandall.click()
time.sleep(10)
a=[]
va=[]
sik = driver.find_element((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='readContractAccordion']"))


print(sik)

for i in sik:
        try:
            print(driver.find_element((By.CLASS_NAME, "readHeading"+str(i))))
            print(driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "readCollapse" +str(i)))
            print(i)
        except:
            print("Elements finished")
            break
```

[The link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSoH4.png)
HTML

```
<div class="card shadow-none mb-3">
        <div class="card-header bg-light card-collapse p-0" id="readHeading1">
        <a class="btn btn-link btn-block text-dark d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center py-2" data-toggle="collapse" href="#readCollapse1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="readCollapse1">
        1. name 
    <span class="accordion-arrow">
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-down small"></i>
        </span>
        </a>
        </div><div id="readCollapse1" class="readContractFunction collapse show" aria-labelledby="readHeading1" style="">
        <div class="card-body p-3"><form>
        <div class="form-group">BNB <i>
        <span class="text-monospace text-secondary">string</span></i></div></form></div></div></div>
```

Update:
[Error furas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqvY2.png)

page:https://etherscan.io/token/0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52#readContract

Comment: `shadow-non mb-3` is not one class but two classes - ``shadow-non` and `mb-3` - and Selenium has problem when there is two or more classes because it treats it as single class and it converts to CSS `.shadow-non mb-3` with `dot` before first class but it should convert to `.shadow-non.mb-3 ` with two dots and without space.

Comment: you try to search by class name `readHeading1` but it is `id`, not `class`, and you should use `By.ID`

Comment: maybe first use `print(sik)` to see what you get - `find_element` get only first element, and you should use `find_elements` with char `s` at the end to get all elements. And later you should rather use `for i in range(len(sik)):` to get number in variable `i`

Comment: better in question (not in comment) you should add Link to this page so we could test code on real page.

Comment: it seems you try to scrape data from `etherscan.io` but it has [API](https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/tokens) and maybe you could get data without scraping. It should run much faster because it doesn't need to use Selenium.

Comment: you didn't add link to this page but I found that it display data in `<iframe>` but `Selenium` need to use `switch_to.frame(...)`  to get data from this frame.

Comment: Thanks. I tried find_elements with sik but it didn't work at the time.Etherscan api doesn't have the functions for returning these values hence the scraping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found few mistakes and problems:

- values are in `<iframe>` and `Selenium` treats it as separated page and it needs `driver.switch_to.frame(...)` to access values.
- you use `By.CLASS_NAME` to get `readHeading` and `readHeading` but you have to use `By.ID`
- I don't understand what you try to do with `sik` because you use `find_element` (without `s` at the end) to get `sik` so it gives only one element - but later you try to use it with `for`-loop, and you expect to get number for `readHeading` and `readHeading`. I assumed that all tokens have always 9 elements on page and I used `for i in range(1, 9):`

---

Minimal working code.

It may need some changes - ie. it could use `WebDriverWait` instead of `sleep` - but at this moment it works.

```
from selenium import webdriver
#from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
#from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

url = 'https://etherscan.io/token/0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52#readContract'

#driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(5)  # JavaScript needs time to add elements on page

frame = driver.find_element_by_id('readcontractiframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[text()="[Expand all]"]').click()
time.sleep(0.5)  # JavaScript needs time to expand all

for i in range(1, 9):
    print('---', i, '---')
    print(driver.find_element_by_id(f"readHeading{i}").text)
    print(driver.find_element_by_id(f"readCollapse{i}").text)
```

Result:

```
--- 1 ---
1. name
BNB string
--- 2 ---
2. totalSupply
16579517055253348798759097 uint256
--- 3 ---
3. decimals
18 uint8
--- 4 ---
4. balanceOf
<input> (address)
Query
uint256
--- 5 ---
5. owner
0x00c5e04176d95a286fcce0e68c683ca0bfec8454 address
--- 6 ---
6. symbol
BNB string
--- 7 ---
7. freezeOf
<input> (address)
Query
uint256
--- 8 ---
8. allowance
<input> (address)
<input> (address)
Query
uint256
```

Comment: Updated the question with screenshot of my error.

Comment: Your code works, I am trying to automate the process of how many values to read but the xpath find elements gives error.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).

Comment: maybe first run without try/except to see error message - maybe there will be explanation.

Comment: I found problem. You use `range(1000)` so first it uses `0` and searchs `readHeading0` but it doesn't exists. You have to start with `1` - use `range(1, 1000)`. In my code I also use `range(1, 9)` instead of `range(9)`

Comment: Yup, i corrected that.it runs ok now.